Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in normal paragraph with no \\
I have done a lot of googling on this issue and haven't come up with anything that matches my scenario. My apologies if I've overlooked it, please feel free to delete this post if it's a duplicate.
I am getting a plethora of underfull \hbox warnings and, given that I started using LaTeX around 24 hours ago, I have no idea what it means or how to resolve it.
It seems like most occurrences of these warnings are from people incorrectly using \\, but I have no such \\ in my file.
For example, in this excerpt:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % Set 1-inch margins on all sides
\usepackage{amsmath} % For math formatting
\begin{document}
\title{HeMan Pro Calculations and Error Propagation}
\author{ohshitgorillas, Ph.D.s}
\maketitle

\section{Raw QMS data}
This section covers the treatment of raw QMS data, including baseline correction, raw data fitting, and error propagation.
\newline \newline
First, raw data are parsed from the files in C:$\backslash$alphachron data$\backslash$raw. 
The first two lines of data in this file are associated with the pre-analysis baseline,
or PAB, and are sorted separately from the rest of the raw data.

\end{document}

The line beginning with "This section covers" gives an underfull \hbox warning in the absence of any \\.
Note that not all of the text directly below subsection headers gives this warning; sometimes, text under itemized lists gives this warning. I cannot for the life of me determine what sets the underfull text apart from normal text.
How can I get rid of these annoying warnings?
I am using VSCode and MikTex on Windows.

\newline is the same as \, only more to type.

what should I use instead to start a new paragraph and avoid these warnings?

use an empty line. If you want space instead of an indentation, use the parskip package.

\newline\newline does not start a new paragraph it forces a an empty ("underfull") line within one paragraph.  just use a blank line in the source to mark a paragraph break.

How can I make it so that the spacing between paragraphs is consistent with \\? Is that the parskip package?

"How can I get rid of these annoying warnings?" you should not view the warnings as annoying, they are warning you of bad (maximally bad with a badness of 10000) output.
